# Subversion configuration file not found

Tags: ubuntu, svn

I want to change the subversion configuration file (Ubuntu 14.01), as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755906/updating-subversion-servers-configuration-file-not-working).

However, there is no `~/.subversion/servers` file:

`ls subversion`

results in:

```
changelog.Debian.gz
copyright
examples
NEWS.Debian.gz
README
README.Debian
svn_1.6_releasenotes.html
svn_1.7_releasenotes.html
svn_1.8_releasenotes.html
```

Comment: `ls subversion` isn't the same as `ls .subversion` You want the `.subversion` folder (which is "hidden", since it begins with a period/dot character) that is located in your home folder.

Comment: Find Subversion config directory!!! It has common structure in all OSes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617648/where-is-the-users-subversion-config-file-stored-on-the-major-operating-systems) that the configuration file is stored in different locations:

> `~/.subversion/config` or `/etc/subversion/config`

Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 0):

`ls` will only list the 'visible' files. Files starting with a `.` are considered 'hidden' in Linux. 
Use `ls -al` to list the `.subversion` folder.

If it doesn't exist, just create the folder and file.